# mysql shell is not able to connect to mysql server

Tags: mysql, command-line

I am using windows machine. Everything is successfully installed. When I try to write `mysql-js> mysql -u root -p` in my MySql shell , it is showing `unexpected identifier` error. What should I write to connect to the mysql server?

Comment: what does it mean: `it is showing unexpected identifier`

Comment: this is the error that I am getting in my shell

Comment: have you installed successfully

Comment: yes, If i connect through mySql workbench gui, it is working fine, but somehow when I try to do it via shell it is not working

Comment: is your charset correct?

Comment: yes,it is correct

Comment: What is the complete command line statement you try to execute and what is the full complete error message you get?

Answer (score 43):

Just check you are in which mode.
To go in sql mode

```
mysql-js> \sql
```

To connect:

```
mysql-js> \connect root@localhost
```

and enter password

Comment: thank you, it works. Though I didn't understand..why I cannot use `mysql -h hostname -u username` inside this shell, since it is a mysql-shell

Comment: `MySQL Error 2005: No such host is known 'localhost;'`  I got this type of error even though I made sure by going into MYSQL Workbench that my host is localhost .

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
\connect root@localhost
```

later id it is in JS mode switch to sql

```
\sql
```

check out this blog
[Starting off with MySQL shell 8.0 on Windows](https://mysqlshell.blogspot.com/2019/03/starting-with-mysql-shell-80-on-windows.html)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to run the `mysql` program from within the mysql client shell. This is wrong. You can run `mysql` only at a **command.exe** prompt.

```
C:\> mysql -u root -p
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 72
Server version: 8.0.1-dmr MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

At this point, you're in the mysql shell, which has been run from the Windows command shell. You can't run programs within the mysql shell, but you don't have to.

This is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html

Once you are in the mysql shell, you can connect to a new server with the `connect` command. But this is uncommon to do this. It's sufficient to connect when you invoke the mysql shell.

```
mysql> connect mydatabase 127.0.0.1
```

The user & password used for this connection are the ones you specified when you first invoked the mysql shell.

This is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html

Answer (score 2):

You may want/need to switch to SQL more using \sql - see \help for help

Answer (score 0):

Better late then never... I had the same issue.
This worked for me

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path="my-server" --user=account --host=10.0.2.15 --password
Enter password:
```

Then enter the password, it will be stored.

If you connect, like below, it will work

```
mysql-js> \connect account@10.0.2.15
Creating a session to 'account@10.0.2.15'
Fetching schema names for autocompletion... Press ^C to stop.
Your MySQL connection id is 1254 (X protocol)
Server version: 8.0.12-commercial MySQL Enterprise Server - Commercial
No default schema selected; type \use <schema> to set one.
```

Please find all further details on this link. It is where I found the solution: https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-shell-8-0-12-storing-mysql-passwords-securely/